# How to prevent InstallShield Limited Edition from making some shortcuts "Run as Administrator"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installshield-2015

I am using InstallShield 2015 Limited Edition with Visual Studio 2010 to create an installer for a variety of different files, including executables, some Excel spreadsheets, and html pages. The executable files are created by NetBeans. The installer works fine, except for the following behavior with a created shortcut that I don't understand.

NetBeans creates 2 executables: myapp.exe, which is 32-bit, and myapp64.exe, which is 64-bit. I am creating non-advertised shortcuts for these two files. The shortcut for myapp64.exe is created as a "Run as Administrator" shortcut, where the little shield picture is embedded in the shortcut icon, and double clicking the icon brings up the typical prompt window when trying to run an app as administrator. When looking at the Compatibility tab in the shortcut properties, "Run this program as an administrator" has been checked for all users.

The shortcut for myapp.exe is "normal". It can be run as administrator from the right-click context menu, but it is not forced to do so because "Run this program as an administrator" is not checked on the Compatibility tab.

I would like for both shortcuts to be created as "normal", to avoid the annoying prompt window, but I can't figure out why the shortcut for myapp64.exe is created as a "Run as Administrator" shortcut. I checked myapp64.exe with the MT tool, but there is no manifest, and the properties for myapp64.exe do not require admin privileges anywhere that I can find. I can't find any InstallShield settings that would make the shortcut "Run as administrator". I have deleted and re-created the shortcut in the installer project, but that doesn't solve the problem. If I manually modify the shortcut for myapp64.exe after installation to uncheck "Run this program as an administrator", the app runs fine.

Finally, this behavior doesn't seem to happen all the time.  It happens in Windows 7, but does not seem to happen in Windows 10. I am only working with 64-bit operating systems.

Any ideas what is going on, or how to prevent the myapp64.exe shortcut from being created to run as an administrator?  Is the Windows Installer seeing something that is causing it to make the shortcut this way?

I posted in the Flexera forum for InstallShield LE, but didn't get a response.

Thanks!

Comment: InstallShield doesn't have any options that control this. Are you seeing this on a fresh install of Windows, or is this possibly residual of changes you've made? Is the text "setup" or "install" part of the elevating app's name or version block (details tab of Windows)?

Comment: It is happening on fresh installs.  The shortcut name is "MyApp Nimbus".  I have folders "x32" and "x64" for the 32-bit and 64-bit shortcuts.  I also made the shortcut name "MyApp Nimbus x64" and put it in the x32 folder, but the same problem happened.  I don't see the text "setup" or "install" in the name or version block for either the shortcuts or the executables.

Comment: Previously, I was using a Visual Studio Installer project.  I didn't have this problem, but it would only make advertised shortcuts, which I didn't want, so I switched to InstallShield.

Comment: When you say "fresh installs" do you mean of Windows or of your app? If the latter, there could be residual registry settings, such as app compat options, that persist outside the installation. Does your exe's name appear in the registry, especially when not installed?

Comment: I believe I have found the problem, based on your hint!  In the registry, I found that the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers had an entry for MyApp64.exe set to RUNASADMIN.  I deleted it, and the installer works as expected.  Our app needs admin privs to install updates.  Perhaps some users set the app to always run as admin, and as you point out, this reg key doesn't get deleted by an uninstall/reinstall.